why don't we create processes from scratch and make it a "fork", in linux?
why in Linux do we not create a process from scratch, as "init" is created, but create a "fork" of it by the method of branching?

Once you already have a process, what would it mean to create from scratch? Who would be doing this creating, and why?

So much information is inherited by the child from the parent: environment, open files, pipes, user, group, process group etc. That parent/grandparent tree is a cornerstone of Linux-type systems. Without it, creating a process "from scratch" would involve passing 50+ accurate parameters to the kernel (which, as the ultimate resource manager, needs to know it all). Process 1 is a helpless baby orphan with the Kernel as midwife.

@ChrisDavies  Thanks. I expected this to be closed (possibly as opinion-based), but I would defer to the excellent Duplicate link anyway. I didn't stress the benefit of fork() creating a pair of identical twins that know everything about what the other has done and intends to do in the future; nor the efficiency (and elegance) of copy-on-write. I called my consultancy Pipe Dreams Ltd: many of my codes never execve() at all -- they just clone themselves into a team.

Such a very large majority of processes are created as part of a cooperating set that shares context (open files, current directory, environment variables, …), and the tweaks to any new process's context are so specific to what exactly it was created for, that it's simplest to just twin the parent process and let its code running in the new process make whatever changes are necessary before execveing whatever's next.
Clean-slate processes are the tiny-minority exception, not the rule.
